# Word percentage program for Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, word-count

I'm working on a slightly improved version of famous WordCount program, which should output what percentage of the book does the word take. For example:

```
...
war 0.00002332423%
peace 0.0034234324%
...
```

Basically, I need to count all the words, count occurence of each of them, divide this set of values by total count. So there should be at least two jobs:

**Job1**

- Takes `input` directory and produces two output directories: `output1` and `output2`
- Mapper: write pairs `(word, 1)` to `output1`, write pairs `("total_count", 1)` to `output2`
- Reducer: sum up pairs with the same keys to make `(word, n)` in `output1`, calculate total count to make `("total_count", N)` in `output2`

**Job2**

- Takes `output1` and `output2` as input folder, writes the results to `output3`
- Mapper: doesn't do anything, just writes down the same pairs it gets
- Reducer: takes single value and divides it by `total_count`, writes the result to `output3`

My problems:

1. I'd like to avoid going through original input twice, that is why I'm trying to calculate both word count and total count in Job1. But I do not understand how to avoid mixing up the results in one output. I have tried to use `MultipleOutputs` but in this case the results of the mapper do not get into reducer.
2. Job2 requires multiple inputs and moreover it needs to read `output2` first, because without total count it is useless to read the results from `output1`. I feel that this is the wrong way of working with MapReduce (we should not use any kinds of synchronization) but do not see the correct one.
3. Mapper in Job2 does nothing useful and will just waste processor time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a thought on using a single Job:

`total_count` can be calculated from the map phase of the first job. Actually, it is already counted as `MAP_OUTPUT_RECORDS`. This is the sum of all the map output `(key, value)` pairs. So, if you always have 1 as value, then this sum is what you want, i.e. the total number of words in your document (with repetition).

Now, I don't know if you can get this counter in the configuration of the reducers. Then, you could just output for each word the pair `(word, wordCount/MAP_OUTPUT_RECORDS)`. I think you can do this through:

New API:

```
context.getCounter("org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$Counter", "MAP_OUTPUT_RECORDS").getValue();
```

Old API:

```
reporter.getCounter("org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$Counter", "MAP_OUTPUT_RECORDS").getValue();
```

Comment: Looks like a very good solution, but there are two problems: it is hard to get counters of mapper in reducer (I have found solutions only for old api) and reducer can start its jobs before all mappers have finished theirs jobs

Comment: Regarding the first problem, I haven't tried that, so I don't know. Did you try the New API solution in my answer? Regarding the second problem, this is not a problem, I believe, because it is not exactly like that. Reducers start the shuffling phase before all mappers are finished, but the reduce phase starts only when all mappers have finished. Otherwise, some of their input pairs could be missing.

Comment: Regarding the first problem again, maybe you should have this command in the `setup()` method? This post might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13609028/is-there-a-list-of-all-standard-not-custom-hadoop-mapreduce-counters

Comment: Used the old API to get the counter but everything else works just fine, thank you for help

Comment: Won't this cause a problem if we use it along with the combiner class?

Comment: @Maverickgugu Nope. MAP_OUTPUT_RECORDS is not affected by the combiner. Combiners have their own input and output records counter.

Answer (score 0):

A non-optimized approach would be to create a special word (like "00000") and use it to count all the words.  Mapper 1 would write out (word, 1) and ("00000", 1) for each word it encounters.  Reducer 1 would then count all of the words as well as calculate the total (the count for "00000").

The next job would have a passthrough mapper and the reducer would calculate the percentages.  The trick here is (1) have a single reducer and (2) choose your "00000" word so that it gets sorted before all other words.  In this way, the total is passed to Reducer 2 first and is known for all subsequent word counts.

Comment: I've also thought about this approach but I think we can't rely on special words like "00000" cause there is no garanty that such sequences of symbols are not present in the input text